# Running an executable file in PHP

Tags: php, latex, executable

I want to compile a latex file in my PHP code, but it doesn't work. I set the permission of this file to 777. I have the following commands in my code:

```
$command = '/usr/bin/latex test.tex';
$output = exec($command);
```

When I try a simple "Hello World!" c++ executable file, it works:

```
$command = './hello';
$output = exec($command);
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: did you set the permission of the file or of /usr/bin/latex ?

Comment: Does the first work if you provide the full path of test.tex?

Comment: @evan Yes, both of them.

Comment: @ Eric No, the full path doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Di you set the permission of the file `test.txt` or the file `/usr/bin/latex`? Because `/usr/bin/latex` need to be executable by `www-data` or whatever you websever is run as.

Comment: I just copied latex to the current directory and set the permission. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that latex depends on environment variables which are not being set properly.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using

```
exec($command, $output, $retval);
var_dump($output);
```

in this way you can get the output (if any) of the run.. it may help detect any errors

also, try to use this instead:

```
pcntl_exec ( string $path [, array $args [, array $envs ]] )
```

so you can pass arguments and environment values in a more clean way